# Is it possible to simplify this method?

Tags: ruby, oop, methods, simplify

I'm using a test method to model a method in a cli tool I'm making, in order to work on the method in isolation. It's a very simple method and I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible. I've managed to simplify the method to this:

```
LOGS = [{ "first_log" => ["first task"] }, { "second_log" => ["second task"] }, { "third_log" => ["third task", "additional task"] }]

LOG_NAME = "second_log" 

def output
  LOGS.each { |log| 
    if LOG_NAME
      puts "-#{log.keys.first.to_s}:", " Tasks: #{log.values.join(",")}" if log.key?(LOG_NAME)
    else
      puts "-#{log.keys.first.to_s}:", " Tasks: #{log.values.join(",")}" 
    end
    }
end
```

The aim here is that when the function is called, if there is a LOG_NAME present it outputs just that log (hash object) and its tasks. If no LOG_NAME is present it outputs all logs (hash objects) in the LOGS array.

This works fine, but my question is: is there a way to make this method even simpler? I feel like I can get rid of the if/else logic and streamline it more but I just cannot conceive of how. I've also tried using rubocop but it 1) suggests similar if/else logic 2) suggests corrections that don't actually output anything.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Your `LOGS` constant seems weirdly defined to me. Would it make more sense to define it as a `Hash`, not an `Array`, like this: `LOGS = {"first_log" => ["first task"], "second_log" => ["second task"], ... }`?

Comment: I'm also a bit confused by the `LOG_NAME` **constant**. Why is it a **constant**?

Comment: These are both just a way to model the objects that I am working with in the actual cli tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could improve this code by separating the filtering of the logs from the printing of the logs. This approach reduces duplication and I think better describes the problem.

```rb
LOGS = [{ "first_log" => ["first task"] }, { "second_log" => ["second task"] }, { "third_log" => ["third task", "additional task"] }]

LOG_NAME = "second_log" 

def output
  LOGS.select { |log|
    LOG_NAME ? log.key?(LOG_NAME) : true
  }.each { |log| puts "-#{log.keys.first.to_s}:", " Tasks: #{log.values.join(",")}"  }
end
```

Comment: This is a good idea, I like the separation of selecting the log to print and the actual printing. My one hangup (which may be an unjustified one) is if this is necessarily 'simpler' or not. I mainly worry that if I showed this code to someone else it might not be immediately clear what I am trying to do, although that might have more to do with my own ability to read code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just skip the iteration for the matching condition?

```
def output
  LOGS.each do |log|
    next if LOG_NAME && log.key?(LOG_NAME)
    puts "-#{log.keys.first.to_s}:", " Tasks: #{log.values.join(",")}" 
  end
end
```

This makes it easier to digest the code that if `LOG_NAME` and log's key has `LOG_NAME` in it then skip, else continue the execution.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I think this does more or less achieve what I was aiming for, however I have to say I prefer the previous (now selected as accepted answer) answer, simply out of personal preference (I like the segmentation of each step, i.e. the select then print of each element in the returned array).